# spring-boot-configuration-processor does not generate metadata in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, eclipse

I'm using the spring-boot-configuration-processor to generate some metadata from my `@ConfigurationProperties` class and use it in Eclipse to generate proposals in the application.properties file. The metadata (JSON) should be generated in the target folder of the project folder after the build, but it isn't.

Here's the `@ConfigurationProperties` class:

```
package com.hakim.config;

import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "rsa")
public record RsaKeyProperties(RSAPublicKey publicKey, RSAPrivateKey privateKey) {
    
}
```

And here's the main class:

```
package com.hakim;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;

import com.hakim.config.RsaKeyProperties;

@EnableConfigurationProperties(RsaKeyProperties.class)
@SpringBootApplication
public class JwtApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JwtApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I've tried configuring the project in eclipse to use spring-boot-configuration-processor as an annotations processor but still no metadata generated.